# How to route from one controller action method to another controller action method without displaying controller name in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two different MapRoutes in Route.config as follows...

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Index",action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SubjectRoute",
    url: "{action}", 
    defaults: new { controller = "Subjects", action = "Subjects" }
);
```

and my `@HTML.ActionLink` is as follows in `Index` action method which is in `IndexController`

```
@Html.ActionLink("SUBJECTS", "Subjects","Subjects", new { }, new { @class = "text" })
```

Now when I click on SUBJECTS link in Index action method, it should go to Subjects action in Subjects controller with out displaying controller name in the URL.

How can this be done?

Comment: You cant - your routes need to be able to be distinguished (and both the routes you have shown are identical - they both consist of one segment)

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to have something to distinguish the different controllers.

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SubjectRoute",
    url: "Subjects", 
    defaults: new { controller = "Subjects", action = "Subjects" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Index",action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

With the above, calls to

```
@Html.ActionLink("SUBJECTS", "Subjects","Subjects", new { }, new { @class = "text" })
```

should generate

```
/Subjects
```

The default and more general route will now catch all other requests and route them to the `IndexController`which now acts as the site root/index.

for example assuming

```
public class IndexController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Index() {...}
    public ActionResult ContactUs() {...}
    public ActionResult About() {...}
}
```

the available routes based on above controller are

```
/
/Index
/ContactUs
/About
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am working on this.